# Trigger event depending on local state on component unmount in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component with some internal state that is not being propagated throughout the application just on certain events.

```
const FunComponent = (initialDescription, onSave) => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('initialDescription');

  const handleDescriptionSave = () => {
    onSave(description);
  }

  return ( ... );
}
```

My issue is that the component can get unmounted by something higher up in the component tree, and at that point I would want to force-trigger `onSave`. Great - i thought - I can just write a useEffect with an empty dependency array, and it will be run on unmount.

The issue is that both the `onSave` prop and the `description` state is something my useEffect cleanup depends on.

If I add them to the dependency array, it will save with the previous description value on every description change. I don't want that.
If I don't add them to the dependency array, it will just use the initial `onSave` and `description` value on unmount.

```
const FunComponent = (initialDescription, onSave) => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(initialDescription);

  const handleDescriptionSave = () => {
    onSave(description);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => { onSave(description) };
  }, [onSave, description])

  return ( ... );
}
```

What hack I came up with is to store the callback in a ref, and have an effect to keep it up to date, and call the ref on unmount:

```
const FunComponent = (initialDescription, onSave) => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(initialDescription);

  const handleDescriptionSave = useCallback(() => {
    onSave(description);
  }, [onSave, description]);

  const handleDescriptionSaveRef = useRef(handleDescriptionSave);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleDescriptionSaveRef.current = handleDescriptionSave;
  }, [onSave, description]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => { handleDescriptionSaveRef.current(); };
  }, []);

  return ( ... );
}
```

But this seems super-duper hacky.

Is there a general recommended pattern for this I fail to recognise? Will this fail in some way? Is this a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.

Your approach does not look as something bad. You can use special hook for it like this https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useUnmount.ts

In our case you can provide two args to hook: cb and args

```js
const useUnmount = (fn: () => any, ...args): void => {
  const fnRef = useRef(fn);

  // update the ref each render so if it change the newest callback will be invoked
  fnRef.current = () => fn(...args);

  useEffectOnce(() => () => fnRef.current());
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I will not feel that bad about my solution and I will try this exact hook you linked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could store the callback directly into the ref without `useCallback()`:

```
const FunComponent = (initialDescription, onSave) => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(initialDescription);

  const handleDescriptionSaveRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    handleDescriptionSaveRef.current = () => onSave(description);
  }, [onSave, description]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => { handleDescriptionSaveRef.current(); };
  }, []);

  return ( ... );
}
```

Comment: That's a good point, I'm overengineering it a bit with trying to not update a mutable reference, but simply calling useCallback is actually a much heavier operation.